# Macbook Air Caps Lock Delay in Windows 8

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro, caps-lock, keybindings, windows

I have remapped <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to <kbd>Backspace</kbd> in Windows 8 using SharpKeys on my Macbook Air, but there is a noticeable delay that prevents me from quickly pressing the key to backspace. The <kbd>Delete</kbd> has no such delay.

I have installed the Boot Camp Windows Support software.

Apparently this is a hardware limitation to prevent people from hitting <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, but OS X can get around it.

How can I prevent this delay on Windows 8?

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked on StackOverflow and SuperUser as well as here. Here's a link to the Ask Different answer that points you to other possible solutions.

[How to remove caps lock delay on Apple MacBook Pro aluminum keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81234/how-to-remove-caps-lock-delay-on-apple-macbook-pro-aluminum-keyboard)

The easiest solution would be to use a third party keyboard, although that can have its own disadvantages.